# Google finding "hidden" Wordpress pages

Tags: google, wordpress

An SEO friend of mine advised that if I just add a page to a Wordpress site - even if its not linked from anywhere - would be enough for Google to find that page.

Can anyone advise if this is correct, and if so, what mechanism allows Google to find the page?  I can posit a couple of things, but with some skepticism.   Does Google rely on Google Analytics - which presumably would rely on having analytics set up on the account to do this?  A pingback mechanism ?  Something else?

Comment: WordPress plugns like Yoast make XML sitemap files that list all the pages.   So in addition to all the ways that secret URLs leak listed in the other questions, WordPress often leaks them intentionally.

Comment: Ah. That's an excellent thought and most likely vector! Doh - I should have thought of it. Thank you.